# how to color button and keep state?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have 3 buttons and a each button presenting a different list. Only one list can be presented at a time, and I want the button to be colored when it's list presented....

currently I have managed to highlight the button with css using:

```
button:active {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

in my css file but when I click somewhere else in the page the highlighting is gone, I want something to color the button as long its list is presented.

this is my buttons:

```
  <button md-button (click)="setListToDisplay(0)" class="md-primary">List1</button>

  <button md-button (click)="setListToDisplay(1)" class="md-primary">List2</button>
</div>

<md-content>

      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of items>
        <div>id: {hetId(item)}}</div>
        <br>
        <div>name: {{getName(item)}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>

</md-content>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class bindings to your buttons.

For example:
 `[class.yourClass]="selectedGroupNumber == 0"` will add class `yourClass` to the button element whenever `selectedGroupNumber` equals `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't maintain a state in CSS. The only states that exist are hover, active, focus and checked. You need to toggle a class on your button when it is clicked.

http://jsbin.com/xudezupasi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```js
var button = document.getElementById("dog");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button.classList.toggle("showing");
},false)
```

```css
#dog{
  background:red;
  height:50px;
}

.showing{
  background:teal !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="dog"></div>
```

You can also use the checkbox hack but it means changing your html. Here is an article on the hack, https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

The idea is that you use the pseudo element `:checked` to add states to your html. It requires you hiding the checkbox and working with the label or getting clever.